# How to create the code behind subscribe button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I need to create the subscribe button in my site, so that if the user click on enter or submit, the system send the email to my email address for information which user enters in the form. I am trying to do this using html. However the code:

```
<a href="mail to: someone@example.com">
```

is trying to open the hotmail or inbuild software like outlook, microsoft software to create and send the email. But I need the html with any (javascript or jquery) codes to be made only inside the html code to send the email directly to my email address.

**I think the people who mark negative are more talented than anyone else in the world as they think that everything is known by everyone. Please stop marking the question as negative as I think these questions can be solution for people who are new or have the same question in the mind.**

Comment: If you want do something like feedback form (it's an example for OP, don't pay attention), you're need to use server-side scripts.

Comment: Server side scripting is the standard way to do this.  Otherwise, it's up to the web browser and desktop environment setup, how mailto links are opened.  There's no SMTP ( eg email sending ) support built directly into web browsers, so it always has to launch _some_ other program or website to send the email.  If you don't want to set up the script yourself, you might be able to find a SaaS API you can integrate into your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the people who mark negative are more talented than anyone else in the world as they think that everything is known by everyone. Please stop marking the question as negative as I think these questions can be solution for people who are new or have the same question in the mind.

Yes on checking the details on internet and information from **@ya.ymer** and **@Daniel Farrell**. The solution which I receive is to achieve this task via **server side script**. I was trying to achieve it via browser but it is not possible.

Thanks